# How to use variable in Linux sed command

Tags: sed

I have already read some topic but there is no similar to mine.

I need to pass to sed command with a $value but its too hard :

```
sed "1,$valued" filename.txt
```

like

```
sed "1,4d" filename.txt
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

That's trying to use a variable called `$valued`.

So you can either:

`1,${value}d`.

Or set `$valued` to `4d`.

Comment: @SPD If Sobrique answered your question satisfactorily you should select it as the answer so Sobrique can get credit.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
sed "1,$value"d filename.txt
```

`$value` is a shell variable (I assume you were already doing that). So you just needed a way to separate the variable name from what comes next (to avoid evaluating `$valued`). Quote marks do the job just fine since the shell removes them before calling `sed`.